# Disable listing of files available for download

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload, upload, blueimp

I wanted to let users upload images on my website, and for that, I've found [the perfect solution](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). I am having trouble in fine-tuning the settings to my need though.

## Why am I posting it here?

- On the support section, I found [this message](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/README.md#support).

## What I want

- I want my users to be able to upload images.
- Maximum two images can be uploaded by one form-filler. (***One***, if this will be too complicated for an SO solution)

## Problems

- Currently, the form shows up all the files that have already been uploaded. I don't want that to happen. Those who are about to upload, shouldn't see already uploaded list of photos.
- Currently, there is no limit to the number of files that can be uploaded. I found two places `jquery.fileupload-validate.js:67` and `UploadHandler.php:99`, where I thought it could be remedied. But it seems like those fields only limit the number of uploads that can exist on the server.

## What I tried

- On `jquery.fileupload-validate.js:67` , I found a pretty neat configuration. `maxNumberOfFiles: 10`. It is disabled by default(by commenting). This is exactly what I want. I want restrict more than 1 file uploads, but I want that for only one user. Currently, this limit applies to the number of files on the server `server/php/files/` which resticts any more uploads after one user uploads an image. Hence, I **did not** use this config even though I found it.
- On `index.html:112` to `index.html:154` there is a template to display available files for download. ***Although I'm pretty sure this is whats causing the problem***, I was not able to disable it without making file-listings for uploads to disappear as well. There are a lot of dependencies I'm yet not familiar with. I'd appreciate the help.

### If I had to paint a picture of the problem

- I want this to happen

  - Upload list should show after user clicks Add Files and selects files.
    [image: Fig: List of Files Ready to Upload should be visible. Upon Upload, the upload message should be visible]
  - Fig: List of Files Ready to Upload should be visible.
  - Upon Upload, the upload message should be visible.
  - But on reload, that should disappear.
- I do not want this to happen

  - List of files available for download, from the `server/php/files` should not show.[image: Fig: The Files that have been uploaded to the server are also being fetched. This should not happen]
  - Upon reload, the files from the server are also showing up. This should not happen
  - I want list of files to be uploaded to show up only during uploading
  - I don't want my uploaded files to show up as available for download.

## Fork

- Here's the clone link `https://github.com/siddhantrimal/jQuery-File-Upload.git`
- Please check it out.

## Resources

- Documentation

  - [Overview](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki)
  - [What each of the plugin-files does](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Plugin-files)
  - Documentaion also mentions, [how to limit file selection](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) (Unfortunately, no 'how to hide list of images available for download?'). But I was unable to do it myself after one too many tries. I need help in this.

Answer (score 1):

i do not know if you found your answer, but i had the same problem.

I just went to main.js and... I commented the following lines:

```
// Load existing files:
// $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
// $.ajax({
//     // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
//     //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
//     url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
//     dataType: 'json',
//     context: $('#fileupload')[0]
// }).always(function () {
//     $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
// }).done(function (result) {
//     $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
//         .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
// });
```

just it.

I hope to help others.